# Select columns in a table and if a row is null, make it empty string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Books] 
WHERE [BookID] = 7
```

I want to select this table and if ANY of the rows in the columns, `fiction`, `nonFiction`, and `Horror` have null values, I want the values to be changed to an empty string.

Note: I don't know if it matters but the column types are all `varchar(50)`

Comment: Have you looked at `ISNULL`/`COALESCE`..?

Comment: I just don't know how to put them together. I am not too good with sql

Comment: [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)/[COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: *"I don't know if it matters but the column types are all varchar(50)"* It does, as a result your `WHERE` isn't SARGable, as `BookID` will be implicitly converted to an `int`. `varchar` is *not* a "one size fits all" data type; that is a design flaw you *need* to fix.

Comment: @Larnu I'm hopeful he's only referring to the three columns in bold. Because otherwise, yeah, that's gonna really kick performance in the nuts.

Comment: *Hopefully*, @JoelCoehoorn , yeah.

Comment: You haven't shown sample data, but it sounds like you have a normalization issue: these three columns should probably be a single `Genre` column, alternatively in a separate `BookGenre` table

Answer (score 1):

Use `ISNULL/COALESCE`

```
SELECT BookID
   , ISNULL(fiction,'') AS fiction
   , ISNULL(nonFiction,'') AS nonFiction
   , ISNULL(Horror, '') AS Horror 
FROM [Books] 
WHERE [BookID] = 7
```